# $this->db->where() third parameter dont escape query on this parameter only or all query generated?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a question about this statement on codeigniter documentation [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=query%20builder#looking-for-specific-data)

> ```
> $where = "name='Joe' AND status='boss' OR status='active'";
> $this->db->where($where);
> ```
>
> `$this->db->where()` accepts an optional third parameter. If you set
>   it to FALSE, CodeIgniter will not try to protect your field or table
>   names with backticks.

It says with that false on third parameter, Codeigniter will not try to protect my field or table names with backticks.
is that means it will not protect all my generated queries 
or just on `$this->db->where()`, where the third parameter is false
Example:

```
$this->db->where('username',$username);
$this->db->where('id is NOT NULL',null,FALSE);
$this->db->get('users')->result_array();
```

Does the query used in above example safe?
will it affect the first `$this->db->where('username',$username)` because of false on third parameter has false and affect all of the query or its safe because its just affect on id `$this->db->where('id is NOT NULL',null,FALSE);`
I Appreciate if you guys/girls can provide an example of the generated query, Because I do now know the bad input for this Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it doesn't affect the entire query, only the `where()` call that you use the parameter with ... Otherwise it wouldn't be a parameter.

And yes, unless you put user input in the condition, it is safe to do that.